# Use class functions after identify the class itself

Tags: java, function, class, if-statement

I have a problem with my current code. I'd like to write a simple monopoly-like game to excercise. There's not much to finish it, but I've stuck at one thing.

I've got a Field class which is extended by a Luck, Property and a Service class. Luck and Service almost are the same.

```
package field;

public class Luck extends Field {
    private final int price;

    public Luck(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
}
```

I have the following problem. I create and store them in a List (as the map goes, 0. element in list is the 1. field on the map, 1. element is the 2. field, etc.)

```
List<Field> fields = new ArrayList<>();
```

Now if one player rolls then move, I should check if he stepped on a Luck or Service field so I could get him the money.

```
Field f = fields.get(player.getPosition());

if (f.getClass().equals(Luck.class)) {
    player.income(fields.get(player.getPosition()).getPrice());

} else if (f.getClass().equals(Service.class)) {
    player.expense(fields.get(player.getPosition()).getPrice());

} else {}
```

The player looks like this:

```
public abstract class Player {
    String name;
    private int wealth;
    private int position;

    public Player(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        wealth = 10000;
        position = 0;
    }

    public void expense(int price) {
        wealth -= price;
    }

    public void income(int price) {
        wealth += price;
    }
```

How could I use the Luck class' functions after the following code ?

```
if (f.getClass().equals(Luck.class)) {
    player.income(fields.get(player.getPosition()).getPrice());
}
```

The error is it can't find the Price symbol which I understand. It's not declared in Fields.java (since not all 3 field has price tag), but I should be able to use it after I've already checked if the class equals Luck, shouldn't I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How could I use the Luck class' functions after

The answer to that specific question is: You *cast* your `f` to `Luck`:

```
((Luck)f).getPrice()
```

e.g.:

```
if (f.getClass().equals(Luck.class)) { player.income(((Luck)f).getPrice()); }
// --------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^-^
```

*(Note I reused `f` there rather than getting it from the list again.)*

You might also look at `instanceof` rather than `getClass().equals(...)`.

---

But if you find yourself using `instanceof` (or `getClass().equals(...)`) and casting a lot, it's worth stepping back and seeing if you can redesign your structure to use a common interface so that you don't really care about the concrete type of the instance, you just ask it to perform its action.

For instance, you might (this is just an off-the-cuff) have an interface like this:

```
interface ActionOnPlayer {
    void performAction(Player p);
}
```

...which is declared but not implemented by `Luck` (making `Luck` an abstract class). (Or `performAction` could be an abstract method on `Luck`.)

And then instead of

```
if (f.getClass().equals(Luck.class)) { player.income(fields.get(player.getPosition()).getPrice()); }
else if (f.getClass().equals(Service.class)) { player.expense(fields.get(player.getPosition()).getPrice()); }
else {}
```

you'd have

```
f.performAction(player);
```

...where each concrete class implements `performAction` in a relevant way.

Answer (score 0):

In your `if`, you don't cast the field to the respective subclass but continue working with `Field` which does not contain a `price`, therefore you get a correct error message. Basically, there are two possibilities:

1. Cast the fields to the respective subclasses inside of the `if`-branches
2. Delegate the handling of the result to the field (the proper OO way):

   ```
   Field f = fields.get(player.getPosition());
   f.visit(player);

   // ...

   public abstract class Field {

       public abstract void visit(Player player);
   }

   // ...

   public class Luck extends Field {

       public void visit(Player player) {
           player.income(this.price);
       }
   }             

   // ...

   public class Service extends Field {

       public void visit(Player player) {
           player.expense(this.price);
       }
   }
   ```